# Trying to copy files with multi-patterns from directory to another directory?

Tags: linux, find, ls

I am trying to copy all files that start with specific pattern from directory to another directory

I tried using the command below,

```
cp 8405T* 1208T* 1783T* 6321T* 9269T* 479T* 1743T* 6527T* 6153T* 144T* 194T* 240T* 279T* 286T* 372T* 376T* 504T* 578T* 609T* 709T* 877T* 880T* 907T* 916T* 948T* 981T* 1008T* 1013T* 1051T* 1063T* 1070T* 1112T* 1128T* 1137T* 1209T* 1225T* 1293T* 1321T* 1323T* 1374T* 1397T* 1416T* 1419T* 1428T* 1435T* 1540T* 1575T* 1742T* 1830T* 1832T* 1889T* 2024T* 2048T* 2102T* 2209T* 2606T* 2741T* 2913T* 4604T* 4648T* 4742T* 4810T* 4814T* 5046T* 5151T* 5234T* 5322T* 5617T* 5902T* 6375T* 6470T* 6474T* 6487T* 6581T* 6646T* 6705T* 6732T* 6734T* 6783T* 8899T* 9528T* 10502T* 10607T* 10694T* 10826T* 12281T* 13094T* 15476T* 28200T* 28231T* 28244T* 28250T* 28264T* 28287T* 4859T* 2092T* 2789T* 5414T* 1863T* 7007T* 7140T* /var/www/html/promo/promoRetired/train
```

but it returns error

```
cp: target ‘/var/www/html/promo/promoRetired/train’ is not a directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are attempting to use `/var/www/html/promo/promoRetired/train` as a destination, then the error message is probably correct, and there exists a `train` FILE, and it is not a directory, and therefore all the preceding arguments may not be copied into the `train` FILE inside of `/var/www/html/promo/promoRetired/`. What is the output of `ls  -la /var/www/html/promo/promoRetired/`?

Comment: Really its all my fault, there is a directory before /train which is upload, trying for one hour with no success, thanks for solving it